# Replacement for percentage in outlook email

Tags: email, html-email

Im having some difficulty. Im trying to have my email be responsive in outlook clients but its just not having it - It wants a set width in pixels but when I do this it looks rubbish in outlook mobile but most frustratingly it looks rubbish in GMAIL because the percentages have been removed.

Is there anyway to get around this? Specifically I want my image to be 100% width with a max width of 600px.

```
                                <tr container">
                                    <td class="content">
                                        <img width="100%"
                                            
                                            src="imagelink" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally what you want is the width attribute for Outlook, e.g. `width="600"`, and the style attribute, which Outlook ignores, set to `width:100%`.

i.e. `<img width="600" style="width:100%;max-width:600px" src="..." />`

Not sure why your percentage is removed in Gmail - but perhaps because your stray quote mark here `<tr container">`. The other possibility (only guessing because you've only posted part of your code) is that you have not inlined the code. Some email clients do not respect embedded CSS, so you can't rely on it. You can use this tool to fix: https://inliner.cm/